# someone pls help me to find the CSS Selector in Cypress for this given image

Tags: cypress

I'm just a beginner in Cypress and having a hard time to find the CSS Selector in the give HTML. This

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the css selector:

```
div#a6f4d0e7f733-0 > span
```

Or, if the text `TGH Pharmacy` occurs only once on the existing webpage you can also use:

```
cy.contains('TGH Pharmacy')
```

Comment: @skfdo accept the answer by clicking the tick sign